# Keeping track of length when using requestBodySourceIO

Tags: haskell, conduit

In `Network.HTTP.Conduit`, `requestBodySourceIO` has this type signature:

```
Prelude Network.HTTP.Conduit Data.Conduit Control.Monad.Trans.Resource> :t requestBodySourceIO
requestBodySourceIO
  :: GHC.Int.Int64
     -> Source IO Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString -> RequestBody
```

First argument is length of body in bytes. What is a good way to pass it the source of `ByteString` while keeping track of running sum of the `Bytestring` fed to it so far? This will help determine at the end of the request where the length passed to it matches the total length of the `Bytestring` passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have some source for the bytes -- call this `source`.
To construct the Source you are going to pass to `requestBodySourceIO`, just append a conduit segment which keeps track of the length:

```
mySource = source =$= processor 0
  where processor sz = do bs <- await
                          let sz' = sz + BS.length bs
                          ...
                          processor sz'
```

And then call `requestBodySourceIO` with `mySource`.

Comment: hmm, `requestBodySourceIO` is predefined function. Isn't it being overwritten here somehow, or are you suggesting writing new one? Also, we have sink here but how do we get the size out of it in above code? It just seems to be consumed within `requestBodySourceIO` above (assuming it can be overwritten somehow) which needs to return `requestBody`.

Comment: Now, that makes more sense! I still have to make sure this typechecks. Before that, one missing piece of this puzzle for me - we pass `mySource` to `requestBodySourceIO` which returns `requestBody`. How do we get the length out of it after `requestBodySourceIO` finishes (which will not return the length)? Can we run another `runConduit` on `mySource` in parallel (some kind of `T` split in the stream where we feed that stream to two different functions)? What will be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Also, you can overwrite the answer with the final version instead of appending to it, if you wish.

Comment: What function(s) take a RequestBody as a parameter?

Comment: It is another function in `Aws` module that makes an HTTP request. We can simulate it with a generic function say `f` that takes `requestBody` as input. I can take it from there.

Comment: I'm interested in functions which consume a RequestBody. What functions would you pass a RequestBody to?

Comment: In case you need more details, this is the function: [`Aws.S3.Commands.PutObject`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aws-0.14.0/docs/Aws-S3-Commands-PutObject.html)

Comment: Note that requestBodySourceIO does not consume the source - it simply wraps it up in one of the RequestBody constructors. Basically it is just one way of creating a GivesPopper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115045/discussion-between-erikr-and-sal).